# How can i send embeds message with message url in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was wondering how can I send a embeds with message URL (this where it gonna send a message embeds)
I was been told to do this:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(id_of_message)
```

And split the link into `/`, and get each individual element you want and you can start fetching every element to get to the message

The mentions channel method is not working when I do this:

```js
const channel = (message
  ? message.mentions.channels.first()
  : interaction.options.getChannel('channel'))

if (!channel || channel.type !== 'GUILD_TEXT') {
  return message.reply({content: 'please tag a channel'})
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is how to send a Message Embed through a Webhook.

A Webhook on Discord is just a URL you can interact with to send messages to a Discord channel.

You can create a webhook like this:

1. [image: Edit Channel]
2. [image: Integrations]
3. [image: Create Webhook]
4. [image: Copy Webhook URL]

You will need to paste this URL in place of the placeholder URL. The following code should be placed at the top of your file!

```js
const { WebhookClient, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Hook = new WebhookClient({ url: 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX' });
```

If you would like to actually send a Message Embed to that hook you can do so like this:

```js
Hook.send({
    embeds: [
        new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Test Embed!')
            .setDescription('This is a test!')
    ]
});
```